# calendar in jQuery datapicker not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

the original format for the datapicker is not showing at all, all i am seeing is just the text and numbers no design.

here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "http://www.byui.edu/prebuilt/stylenew/images/interface/icon_calendar_18x18.jpg",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

When I run this in my browser it shows the calander when i click the button but there is no image on the calander just the prev and next words and the dates in numbers.

Comment: add jquery ui css, [example](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/demos/datepicker/alt-field.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not including [jquery-ui.css](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
     href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/hpUAK/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "http://www.byui.edu/prebuilt/stylenew/images/interface/icon_calendar_18x18.jpg",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```